# DataStore - how to retrieve ID/Name value?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm have a Servlet which saves an entity into datastore and a jsp which displays the content of the table. I've noticed that datastore automatically creates an unique ID/Name for each new row added to a table. When I try to display the ID/Name value in my jsp, I get null value returned. Following is my code. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to get the ID/Name value from the table. Thank you so much in advance.

```
public class RegisterForAccountServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException 
    {

    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    Key userKey = KeyFactory.createKey("RegisterUserKey", email);
    Entity user = new Entity("RegisteredUsers", userKey);
    user.setProperty("email", email);
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    datastore.put(user);


    resp.sendRedirect("/ListOfAllUsers.jsp");
}
```

}

following is the jsp which displays all the registered users:

```
<%
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
//Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);

// Run an ancestor query to ensure we see the most up-to-date
// view of the Greetings belonging to the selected Guestbook.
Query query = new Query("RegisteredUsers");
List<Entity> users = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5));
if (users.isEmpty()) 
{
%>
    <p>no registered users</p>

<%
} 
else 
{
%>

    <%
    for (Entity user : users) 
    {
    %>
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td><%= user.getProperty("ID/Name") %></td>
        <td><%= user.getProperty("email") %></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

   <%
    }//for
}//else
%>
```

Answer (score 5):

The Name/ID is part of the entity key. Use `user.getKey().getName()`.

Comment: This is what I did as per your suggestion: <td><%= user.getKey().getName() %></td>, but did not work.